# How do you capture the result of a POST in the WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a Winforms form with a [WebBrowser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) on it.

I've already figured out how to connect the C# code to the Javascript in the Web Browser control by attaching an instance of a C# class to the [ObjectForScripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx) property, like this:

```
public partial class Browser : Form
{
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptInterface();
    }
}

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ScriptInterface
{
    public void DoSomething(string data)
    {
        // Do something interesting with data here
    }
}
```

... and then call it from the Javascript like this:

```
<button onclick=window.external.DoSomething('with this')/>
```

What I haven't figured out yet is how to capture the result of a POST operation from a form in the WebBrowser control, and use it in my C# code.

Comment: Do you want to intercept the form post? Could you perhaps do it in jQuery instead? Looks like it would be fairly simple to get jQuery to pass the data back to your external method.

Comment: That sounds like it would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use [jQuery `post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) instead of a form post.

Assuming your form has an id of `myForm`:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {     
  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $(this),
  var term = $form.find("input[name='s']").val(),
  var url = $form.attr("action");

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } )
      .done(function(data) {
          //Pass the response back to your code
          window.external.DoSomething(data);
      });
});
```

Comment: Do I remove the `action` attribute from my `<form>` tag, as in `<form method="POST">`?

Comment: No, leave it in there. The `var url...` line uses it to get the URL to post to.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I don't think I'll actually be posting it anywhere, just passing it to the `ScriptInterface`.